# Add shipping rates based on order in cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to do something like following.

If user buy 3 products which total over $30 then next 4 products should be allow 50% on price in WooCommerce WordPress.

I have tried all the way but Didn't found anything useful. I have found some plugins but didn't useful  : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_rates_based_on_cart_amount', 10, 2 );
function shipping_rates_based_on_cart_amount( $rates, $package ) {

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 900 ) { ## Under 900

            unset( $rates['free_shipping:19'] ); // remove: USPS Express (free)
            unset( $rates['free_shipping:21'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand. Overnight (Free)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:25'] );  // remove: Fedex Pty. Overnight ($20)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:26'] ); // remove: Fedex Pty. Saturday Deliv. ($40)

        if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 200 ) { ## Under 200

            // For => "Fedex Stand Overnight ($45)"
            if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:16'] ) )
            {
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:23'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand Overnight ($40)
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:24'] ); // remove: Fedex Pty. Overnight ($50)
            }

            // For => "Fedex 2 days ($20) "
            if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:15'] ) )
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:22'] ); // remove: Fedex 2 days AM ($20)

        } else { ## Between 200 and under 900

            // For => "Fedex Stand 2 days (free)"
            if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:18'] ) )
            {
                unset( $rates['free_shipping:14'] ); // Fedex Ground (Free)
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:15'] ); // remove: Fedex 2 days ($20)
            }

            // For => "Fedex Stand Overnight ($40)"
            if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:23'] ) )
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:16'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand Overnight ($45)
        }

    } else { ## From 900 (up to 900)

        ## 1) FEDEX

        // For => "Fedex Stand. Overnight (Free)"
        if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:21'] ) )
        {
             unset( $rates['free_shipping:18'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand 2 days (Free)
             unset( $rates['free_shipping:14'] ); // remove: Fedex Ground (Free)
        }

        // For    => "Fedex Pty. Overnight ($20)"
        // Or for => "Fedex Pty. Saturday Deliv. ($40)"
        if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:25'] ) || isset( $rates['flat_rate:26'] ) )
        {
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:15'] ); // remove: Fedex 2 days ($20)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:22'] ); // remove: Fedex 2 days AM ($20
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:16'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand Overnight ($45)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:23'] ); // remove: Fedex Stand Overnight ($40)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:24'] ); // remove: Fedex Pty. Overnight ($50)
            unset( $rates['flat_rate:9'] );  // remove: USPS Express ($45)
        }

        ## 2) USPS

        if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:19'] ) ) // For => "USPS Express (free)"
            unset( $rates['free_shipping:4'] ); // remove: USPS Priority (free)

    }

  return $rates;

}
```